# ProbabilityDistribution fails for square root

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, sampling

I would like to sampling data from a distribution `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]`.
I used the code as follows:

```
a = ProbabilityDistribution[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
RandomVariate[a, 10]
```

However, mathematica fails to produce the result.

If I use this code, then it works.

```
a = ProbabilityDistribution[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
RandomVariate[a, 10];
```

It seems that these two are not so different, except for the second one does not have square root.
Can anyone explain this?

Comment: In terms of a tractable formula, a square root can make a big difference.  But in any event, *Mathematica* 10.4 gives me a warning rather than "fails to produce the result":  For *Mathematica* 10.4 I get the following warning:  "Sampling from `ProbabilityDistribution[`$\sqrt{x1^2+x2^2},\{x1, 0 , 1\}, \{x2, 0, 1\}$`]` is not implemented."

Comment: Neither the pdf $f(x,y) = \sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$ nor the pdf $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ is valid or well-defined, as neither integrates to unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html)

```
aDist = TransformedDistribution[
   Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
    y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}];

SeedRandom[0]

RandomVariate[aDist, 10]

(* {0.671686, 1.03103, 1.13352, 0.855141, 0.984159, 1.23482, 0.908538, 0.637849, \
0.551954, 0.735437} *)
```

Note that `Sqrt[x^2+y^2]` is a scalar and unlike your second example, `RandomVariate[a, 10]` should return a list of 10 scalars rather than a list of 10 pairs.

```
Plot[Evaluate@PDF[aDist, x], {x, 0, Sqrt[2]},
 MaxRecursion -> 10]
```

[image]

If `x` and `y` are standard normal rather than uniform then

```
aDist2 = TransformedDistribution[
  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
   y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}]

(* RayleighDistribution[1] *)
```

Comment: I don't follow your comment that $\sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$ is scalar:  the pdf $f(x,y) = \sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$ defines a bivariate space, and random variates drawn from that distribution should be bivariate pairs. [ If the OP is after a scalar -- well ... who knows ... maybe he is ... but that is not what he has set up using `ProbabilityDistribution`

Comment: @wolfies - since the “PDF” was not scaled properly to be a valid PDF and the OP did not use the option `Method -> "Normalize"`, I guessed that the OP meant to find the distribution for `a = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]`. If it turns out that this is not what is intended then I will delete my answer.